# Getting bx to create a private key from known chain code and a private EC WIF key?

Tags: wallet, private-key, bip32-hd-wallets

I was trying to get strong feedback that I really understood a [portion](https://github.com/aantonop/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch04.asciidoc#CKDpriv) of the Mastering Bitcoin Book concerning HD wallets. The picture below is the reference for the question.

[image: HD Private Child Key Derivation]

I checked out the functionality exposed by a [Javascript Brain Wallet](https://coinb.in/#newHDaddress). By entering "123" (is a very poor secret) into a field for a HD brainwallet and the following extended private key emerged: **xprv9s21ZrQH143K2hYgcmBxsUfRw3Kbu3eEGXFJrM8Cqtewuqa6Y6nXbB7tv9HnrBajqjptPsRjL9FmnwLa317jHWJ5dpwTc99C2AiPztPRaxk**.

Clicking the button to the right of the private key got me to another page indicating the master private chain code is **40675733fc35303c1c75bc598716f24af225528da686192ceb567c88313f8885** and the master private key is **L4h3ZSQ3yfFNbovQjTGumvUGEfB1a7oFAhbkhMMFGsdDKoTSwwU8**.

Given these last two pieces of information and an index of 0, is it possible to issue a number a number of bx commands and concatenate their output results to feed a HMAC-SHA512 hash to arrive at private WIF key of **KwMsDozFYQG7SZFwfvFRwWDhfuMJjkE669WxP6SqrpDPsCBrPV4p** public address **15jbcT7wE81s8n2dbEGRFGf65zp7PHrjxh**?  If so, how is this accomplished or does bx need to be complemented by some other command that renders HMAC-SHA512 functionality?

Comment: % echo "L4h3ZSQ3yfFNbovQjTGumvUGEfB1a7oFAhbkhMMFGsdDKoTSwwU8" | bx wif-to-ec
deec675df1bc1d395c6098ee63eacb45036fad781717548f4b8cc00709f5d834

Comment: % echo "L4h3ZSQ3yfFNbovQjTGumvUGEfB1a7oFAhbkhMMFGsdDKoTSwwU8" | bx wif-to-ec | bx ec-to-public 
02430aca0779d7ca52441ee9de2f7b73408ee8229d6c2e42a5c81b65028efc803f

Answer (score 2):

No need for an external program at all:

```
$ KEY=xprv9s21ZrQH143K2hYgcmBxsUfRw3Kbu3eEGXFJrM8Cqtewuqa6Y6nXbB7tv9HnrBajqjptPsRjL9FmnwLa317jHWJ5dpwTc99C2AiPztPRaxk
$ echo $KEY | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-to-address
15jbcT7wE81s8n2dbEGRFGf65zp7PHrjxh
```

Or, because this is non-hardened, you can use the extended public key:

```
$ KEY=xpub661MyMwAqRbcFBd9iniyEccAV5A6JWN5dkAuejXpQEBvnduF5e6n8ySNmP8uWeqNbwFXLHEQkV1shXbNtBV8YCUJPMSuE7bGCvDaZJfUBuP
$ echo $KEY | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-to-address
15jbcT7wE81s8n2dbEGRFGf65zp7PHrjxh
```

Comment: Most excellent...